# Yii2 scroll pages, как убрать $_GET данную

Tags: php, yii2

Я использую https://github.com/kop/yii2-scroll-pager для вывода новостей на страницу.

Все работает отлично, но при прокрутке, на странице меняется $_GET данная в URL

```
https://samp-news.loc/site/news?page=4
```

Как избавиться от этого?

код в моделе

```
 public function getAllNews(){
    $query = $this::find()->where(['status' => $this::ACTIVE_NEWS]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'date' => SORT_DESC
            ]
        ],
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

код в контроллере

```
 public function actionNews(){

    $model = new News();
    $dataProvider = $model->getAllNews();

    return $this->render('news',[
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ]);
}
```

Код в news.php(views)

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'SA-MP News';
use yii\widgets\ListView;
?>

<div class="site-index">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row main-news-block">
            <h1 class="news-page-h1">Новости</h1>
            <ul class="ul-news">
               <?php
               echo ListView::widget([
                   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                   'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
                   'itemView' => 'item_news',
                   'pager' => [
                       'class' => \kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className(),
                       'eventOnScroll' => 'console.log(111)',
                       'triggerOffset' => 3
                   ]
               ]);
               ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно отключить расширение ScrollPager::EXTENSION_HISTORY https://github.com/kop/yii2-scroll-pager#extensions

Для этого нужно указать какие расширения должны быть включены:

```
echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
    'itemView' => 'item_news',
    'pager' => [
        'class' => ScrollPager::className(),
        'eventOnScroll' => 'console.log(111)',
        'triggerOffset' => 3,
        'enabledExtensions' => [
            ScrollPager::EXTENSION_TRIGGER,
            ScrollPager::EXTENSION_SPINNER,
            ScrollPager::EXTENSION_NONE_LEFT,
            ScrollPager::EXTENSION_PAGING,
        ],
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли.